# How to get extendInfo and userInfo object in paytm callback response

Tags: node.js, callback, paytm, userinfo

I want to get custom form fields' values in Paytm payment success response, like customer name, email, contact no, other custom values which I have set.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass all the details in "extendInfo" param in initiate transaction request. Please send them in udf1, udf2 and so on.